# {{ in Laravel form text area data value

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-7

**Update: This is not blade processing but something client side in Vue that is the problem** - See below for the error.

---

How can I safely and easily handle form values which contain `{{` in Laravel 7?

I have a database field which contains, for example,

```
\title{{\titlefont\Huge %TITLE%}\\
{\subtitlefont\large %Subtitle%}}
\author{\authorfont %AUTHOR%}
\maketitle
```

When I try and load that into a `Form::textarea` as a simple data value from a variable it breaks the blade rendering as it tries to interpret the `{{` as the start of a block of Laravel PHP code - which it isn't.

So... how can I solve this in the proper Laravel way (I'm very new to Laravel...) ?

---

Field code:

```
{{ Form::textarea('textitle', $style->textitle, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

The resultant output is:

```
 <textarea class="form-control" name="textitle" cols="50" rows="10">\title{{\titlefont\Huge %TITLE%}\\
{\subtitlefont\large %Subtitle}}
\author{\authorfont %AUTHOR%}
\maketitle</textarea>
```

And nothing is rendered to the browser window. The whole display breaks. It's odd that the browser sees the right HTML but doesn't display it, which makes me suspicious that something else may be at play here, but the culprit is definitely the `{{` in the textarea value.

---

I am using Firefox 78.0.2, if that makes any difference. In Chrome I see a brief flash of the content then it vanishes.

---

Vue error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: invalid escape sequence in

    "\\title"+_s(\titlefont\Huge %TITLE%}\\
{\subtitlefont\large %Subtitle%)+"\n\\author{\\authorfont %AUTHOR%}\n\\maketitle\n"

  Raw expression: \title{{\titlefont\Huge %TITLE%}\\
{\subtitlefont\large %Subtitle%}}
\author{\authorfont %AUTHOR%}
\maketitle
```

Comment: Output of `$style->textitle`?

Comment: Yeah. I really don't know what is happening tbh. The more I look at it the more it looks like something in bootstrap as it seems to be post rendering that kills it.

Comment: What's about `{!! Form::textarea('textitle', $style->textitle, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: Nope, no difference. As I say I'm leaning away from the blade processing and towards bootstrap now.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely something in my app.js that is doing it.

Comment: It's looking like it's Vue that is the culpret - remove the Vue boot code from my app.js and it displays the page ok.

Comment: AFAIK I'm not actually using Vue. Am I? I haven't *knowingly* used it (I didn't even know what it was until now...). So if I disable it will anything in default Laravel/Bootstrap break?

Comment: Then may be you are using vue in your page